# Errors with json_decode in php

Tags: php, json

*We are have json:*

```
{ "list":
       [
        {"id":"4045","value":"Xin Kai"},
        {"id":"4141","value":"YZK"},
        {"id":"4099","value":"ZX"}
       ]
}
```

*For get value we use next code:*

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($json['list'] as $item) {
    print $item['value'].'<br />';

}
```

*But now we get error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...`*

*Tell me please where error in code and how will be right?*

Comment: what var_dump($json) gives you?

Comment: @imel96 problem with decode becouse i make `var_dump($json)` and i get `NULL`, but where error in decode?

Comment: if i make `var_dump($result)`, i get `string...`

Comment: @learner what do you get in that `var_dump($result)`? The full string. because as your example sits, it works: https://eval.in/208543

Comment: http://ideone.com/zzoQHd - it works

Comment: @Darren i get `string(99) "{ "list":[{"id":"4045","value":"Xin Kai"},{"id":"4141","value":"YZK"},{"id":"4099","value":"ZX"}]}"`

Comment: @zerkms in your code `{ "list":[{{` instead of `{ "list":[{`

Comment: @learner: I copied your JSON as-is and it works

Comment: That string has broken UTF characters. JSON string must be a valid UTF string. But even that string does work fine (on php 5.3)

Comment: +1 to zerks answer. That's your issue. If you don't mind, where are you getting this json from?

Comment: @Darren we get Json from CURL, full code http://pastebin.com/mRxZZEMY

But what me need doing that i can get value?

Comment: >>> `windows-1251` <<< JSON document **must be** in `UTF-8`

Comment: @zerkms i see it, me need delete this or other action?

Comment: @learner: you could contact data provider and ask them how to request the data in `UTF-8` properly

Comment: @learner: do we need to guess or read your mind to get the newest data example? <-- it's not irony, I accept that you may think we can read minds, since providing data in such a question must be obvious for *anyone*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `json_decode` you need get json in `utf-8`, in you exmple(if you get json in windows-1251) you need use next code:

#### EXAMPLE FIRST - if you want get array

```
//if you want get array
$json_obj = json_decode(iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",$result), true);
foreach($json_obj['list'] as $item) {
    print $item['value'].'<br />';   
}
```

#### EXAMPLE SECOND - if you wnt get object

```
//if you wnt get object
$json_obj = json_decode(iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",$result));
foreach($json_obj->list as $item) {
    print $item->value.'<br />';   
}
```

#### *Enjoy!*

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're doing this in your code:

```
foreach($json->list as $item) {
```

When you should be doing this:

```
foreach($json['list'] as $item) {
```

As you decoded it as an `array` and **not** as an `object`.

Read More: [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Also, as zerkms said,

[<sup>`>>> windows-1251 <<< JSON document must be in UTF-8`</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498016/errors-with-json-decode-in-php?noredirect=1#comment41629200_26498016)